# Streamlit Deploy Platform or Hosting Service

Tags: deployment, service, hosting, platform, streamlit

So I have a Python Streamlit Source Code and it has a massive size model, in total of around 4-5GB.
Is there any Hosting Service or Platform where could i deploy my Streamlit Project to?

Something like heroku, but currently heroku could connect to Github and Git CLI has 500MB limit.

Anyone know where could i deploy my Streamlit Project?

Comment: That size is big so perhaps you will have to pay. Check the streamlit cloud.

Comment: I do wanna pay, but streamlit cloud is soooo expensive. is there any other platform that could deploy streamlit?